# How to write method for auto update one column based on the other column in the same row rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Users table like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------
| name | email | role | card_amount (integer) |
-----------------------------------------------
| ...  | ...   | ...  | ...                   |
-----------------------------------------------
```

I want to update the role column based on the card_amount column automatically with a specific condition like below:

```
if @user.card_amount >= 100
```

Then the role column will auto update like:

```
@user.role = "buyer"
```

How to make it happens automatically? So everytime the @user.card_amount >= 100 the role colum will have value "buyer".

Or when I go to rails console and update the card_amount to 100, then the role column will also being updated to "buyer"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a `before_save` callback.  eg

```
before_save :update_role

def update_role
  if self.card_amount >= 100
    self.role = "buyer"
  end
end
```

Read this:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html

Comment: Thank you, and where to put this code into? application_controller or user_controller, or user model?

Comment: Put it in User model :)

Comment: Yep, sorry, could have said that but the examples in the link i gave make that quite clear i think.